# Unable to organize my typescript definitions into multiple files

Tags: typescript, lua, typescript-typings, typescript-to-lua

I am writing a TypeScript definition for a Lua library, to be used with the TypeScript-to-Lua transpiler. I am able to get the definition to work and my code runs exactly as expected, but so far I've been unable to find a reasonable way to split my definition into multiple files.

My project is a math library and I have several Lua files such as vec3.lua, mat4.lua, quat.lua, etc. Each of these submodules has a `new` function for creating an "object" in Lua using metamethods. `new` is also being called by the `__call` metamethod so that if you call the Lua table like a function, it will spit out an object.

```lua
local cpml = require "cpml"
local v1 = cpml.vec3(1, 2, 3)
local v2 = cpml.vec3(3, 2, 1)
print(cpml.vec3.add(v1, v2)) -- (4, 4, 4)
print(v1:add(v2)) -- (4, 4, 4)
```

Back to TypeScript, what this essentially means is that for me to create my objects, I need to invoke `__call` as `new` is a reserved word in TypeScript.

```js
declare module "cpml" {
  export namespace cpml {
    type Vec3 = { x: number, y: number, z: number };
    function vec3(x?: number, y?: number, z?: number): Vec3;
    namespace vec3 {
      function add(a: Vec3, b: Vec3): Vec3;
    }
  }
}
```

The above definition *works*, but the caveat is that it is all within the same file. I cannot for the life of me find a way to move that `vec3` namespace into another file and then import it into this file without some error. Whether it's a namespace, an interface, its own module, a class.. nothing I do will allow me to stick that in another file. I always end up with the same issue: my `vec3` function (which **must** be named that to invoke `__call`) complains about a duplicate identifier when i try to import my `vec3` namespace from another file.

```js
declare module "cpml" {
  export namespace cpml {
    const Vec3 = typeof import("./vec3.d.ts").Vec3;
    function vec3(x?: number, y?: number, z?: number): Vec3;
    const vec3: typeof import("./vec3.d.ts").vec3; // nope!
  }
}
```

Any insight into this would be more than appreciated.

Comment: May I ask what the error is and is it on the ```const vec3``` or the ```typeof import("./vec3.d.ts").vec3;``` part of the code?

Comment: The error is duplicate identifier, ie, I have a const and a function both named `vec3`.